# Python - Performance of this code very slow

Tags: python, web-scraping, django, beautifulsoup

This is an excerpt of my html code

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="left_menu">
            <!-- <h2></h2> -->
            <h2>Search</h2>
            <ul class="w_list">
                <li><a href="">Search</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <div class="page_title">Search</div>
        <table class="table table-bordered table-responsive">
            <tbody>
                <tr class="blue">
                    <td colspan="2"><strong>Product Search</strong></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Sr.No.</td>
                    <td>Product Name</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td><a class="product_link" href="#" onclick="search_product(2,53)">Galaxy Note 8</a></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td><a class="product_link" href="#" onclick="search_product(3,53)">Redmi 4</a></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>3</td>
                    <td><a class="product_link" href="#" onclick="search_product(4,42)">Washing Machine 44L</a></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>4</td>
                    <td><a class="product_link" href="#" onclick="search_product(5,53)">Air Conditioner</a></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>5</td>
                    <td><a class="product_link" href="#" onclick="search_product(6,42)">Air Cooler</a></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Below is a method from my Django application

```py
def get():
    arr = []
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(open(os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, 'sample.html')), 'html.parser')
    for a in soup.find_all(lambda tag: tag.name == "a" and "class" in tag.attrs and "product_link" in tag['class'] and len(tag['class']) > 0):
        try:
            if re.match('search_product', a['onclick']):
                obj = {"name": a.get_text(strp=True), "next": a['onclick']}
                arr.append(obj)
        except:
            pass
```

The actual file has around 300K of those repeated `<tr>` tags, each corresponding to a product. The code above takes about 8 minutes to extract the required data on my high-end laptop. How can I improve this code so that it can run faster? Are there any other Python libraries which can do the job faster?

Comment: Please provide more context for your question. What does this code accomplish? That should be stated in the title. Your method doesn’t return anything — is that real code? See [ask], and [edit] your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple things to do to make the HTML parsing faster:

- switch to `lxml` from `html.parser` (`lxml` is the fastest - requires `lxml` to be installed, of course):

  ```
  with open(os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, 'sample.html')) as f:
      soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(f, 'lxml')
  ```
- use more concise, readable and faster [CSS selectors](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) to filter out the desired elements:

  ```
  for a in soup.select("a.product_link"):
  ```
- you can also use a [`SoupStrainer`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#parsing-only-part-of-a-document) to limit the parsing scope:

  ```
  parse_only = bs4.SoupStrainer("a", class_="product_link", onclick=True)
  soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(f, 'lxml', parse_only=parse_only)
  ```
- and, since we've limited the parsing scope to the product links - see if you still need that regular expression `onclick` check at all

Note that you still have a lot of overhead there because of the **synchronous nature of your execution logic** - you are currently processing products one by one *sequentially*. Look into asynchronous solutions using, for instance, `Scrapy`, `grequests`, `asyncio` etc.